# Nodejs Express send res.render and res.json simultaneously

Tags: node.js, express

How can I send res.render and res.json simultaneously in NodeJS with Express. I wanted something like:

```
app.get(basePath, function (req, res, next) {
    //More stuff
    res.json({token: token});
    res.render(path.join(publicPath, '/main'), 
        {mv: mv});
});
```

but it only gives me the token without rendering the page. Using this method:

```
app.get(basePath, function (req, res, next) {
    //More stuff
    res.render(path.join(publicPath, '/main'), 
    {mv: mv, token: token});
});
```

I don't have access to token param (I have to store it in client)

The idea is to avoid to use 2 requests (one for page testing the token and one for generate new token rtesting the old one). And avoid to have a hidden span with the token in every views.

Comment: What you trying to achieve is not secured. You should consider using cookie, or session if the token you are sending if the user is connected. Also, just use a middleware to do the token re-generation. Izio.

Comment: but I read that cookies are more insecure than tokenn because anybody can stole it. I have 15 min only tokens. I don't know exactly what works better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP uses a cycle that requires one response per request. When the client sends a request the server should send only one response back to client. So that you need to send only one response to the client either `res.render()` or `res.json()`.

If you like to set some data like authentication token, you can set on your header using `res.set()` or `res.header()`. [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set)

```
app.get(basePath, function (req, res, next) {

    //More Stuff ...

    res.header('token', JSON.stringify({ token: 'token' })); //use encrypted token
    res.render(path.join(publicPath, '/main'), { mv: mv });
});
```

To set header for all routers or particular set of router you can use [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: great! that will be very usefull for tis case. Lot's of thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) use a middleware to generate the token
2) quick tip, `{token:token}` is the same as `{token}`

Comment: Thanks for the tip (I didn'k know well the sintax) About the middleware, I have private and public pages so with a middleware Iit will generates tokens for public  pages too (I don't know if that is a good practice). And still having the problem of how to send both to the view (the token generated with a middleware and the render of the page).